# Handling click event of switch widget on action bar

Tags: java, android

This is how I added a switch widget to the action bar. I'm already playing with it. But I'm not knowing how to respond to the click events.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    System.out.println("actionbar clicked");
    // Handle item selection
    if (item.getItemId()==R.id.myswitch) {
        Switch actionView = (Switch)item.getActionView();
        actionView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, final boolean isChecked) {
                status = isChecked;
                System.out.println(status);
            }
        });

        return true;   
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This is my switch layout and map resource file

switch_status.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Switch
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:showText="true"
    android:textOff="Free"
    android:textOn="Booked" />
```

map.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/myswitch"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title=""
    android:actionLayout="@layout/switch_status" /> 
</menu>
```

While clicking the switch, It is changing its state, but I cannot see even one msg on the console like "actionbar clicked" & "true" / "false". And there is no error either.

I'm not sure weather this is the correct way of handling clicks on actionbar. If any one can help me with this code, it will be really nice.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Best way for do this using Toolbar .
In Toolbar you can add any view and control this.

Comment: Can you show me a sample? Please. That's a good choice really. But still need to learn about it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set a OnCheckedChangeListener, onOptionsItemSelected is a "onClickListener"

use switch for this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    System.out.println("actionbar clicked");
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.myswitch:
           System.out.println(((Switch)item.getActionView()).isChecked());
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and achieved by following below technique

Added onClick method for switch like below

```
<Switch
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:showText="true"
    android:textOff="Free"
    android:textOn="Booked"
    android:onClick="onSwitch"
/>
```

Implement onSwitch method in Activity as below:

```
public void onSwitch(View view) {
    Switch androidSwitch = findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    if(androidSwitch.isChecked()){
        Log.i("Test","enabled");
    }else{
        Log.i("Test","disabled");
    }
}
```